# How do I register Google Classroom API for push notifications?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, push-notification, google-oauth, google-classroom

I want to create a program that will receive notifications from my Google Classroom in question, and do something with that data. How can I register Google Classroom to react to an event?
I haven't made anything yet, and I don't know anything about Google's APIs. What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

The process of registering the Google Classroom API for push notifications includes authentication, authorization, and parsing a request to Google to tell your Classroom to send these push notifications.

I highly recommend you have basic knowledge of the Google Cloud platform in the Java programming language, unlike me when I tried to do this. Trust me... it wasn't fun.
I do believe you will understand this concept enough to be able to transfer it to your language of choice, I did this in Java, using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE.

Apart from the Google Classroom API, Google features another service to their collection called "Pub/Sub". Pub/Sub stands for Publisher/Subscriber. If you're familiar with how a queue works, think of Pub/Sub as a sort of refined queue system. You have a publisher, who posts messages on a "topic", and a subscriber to the topic who will pull messages from the topic, and choose to "acknowledge" the message or not. Acknowledging a message deletes it from the queue. For example, the publisher code sends the message "Hello, World" to a topic. That message will stay in the topic until a subscriber to that topic chooses to pull the message, read "Hello, World", and acknowledge the message, so it doesn't pop up again when pulling messages. The publisher can send as many messages as it wants. The publisher can send 10 messages, and the subscriber can choose to pull them all and iterate through them or just a few at a time.

This applies to this system because you're going to use a built-in function of the Google Classroom API that allows the API to act as a "publisher" and send update messages to a topic of your choosing. Then, you'll have a separate application checking for updates whenever you'd wish. To simplify it for now, you tell the Classroom API to "Please send update messages to this topic. I only want updates when the teacher edits the course work catalog in any way". This request will be followed by the Classroom API and the program will send messages to your topic whenever a teacher edits, or posts, or deletes, and such more.

If your classroom publisher sent 5 updates in a day, you'll have 5 pullable messages sent to your topic that any subscribing program of that topic can pull and acknowledge.

If you do not understand enough, in your opinion. Please, please do some research on Google Cloud Pub/Sub before continuing, since doing this basically revolves around this service.

Let's do this step-by-step...

1. Create a new project
2. Enable Classroom API and PubSub API
3. Enable Billing
4. Go to "IAM & admin"
5. Give the owner permission to "classroom-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com"
6. Set up credentials for Classroom API and a "UI-based platform" using "User data"
7. Set up the consent screen. Just add an application name for now.
8. Create credentials as an "OAuth Client ID"
9. Choose Application Type > Other. Don't mind the client name
10. Download the JSON file. Rename it to "credentials_temp.json"
11. Create a Gradle based Java project (I'm using IntelliJ). Group id: temp. Artifact id: temp. Project name: temp
12. Add this to build.gradle under "dependencies"

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-classroom:v1-rev135-1.23.0'
```

13. Set the `sourceCompatibility` variable in build.gradle to `11`
14. Import those changes (There may be a little box at the bottom-right saying "import changes" as an option)
15. Put the credentials file in src/main/resources
16. In src/main/java, make a new class. Name it "TempTest.java"
17. Use this code I've written for you

```java
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom;
import com.google.api.services.classroom.model.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.google.api.services.classroom.ClassroomScopes.all;

public class TempTest {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Classroom API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";
    private static List<String> SCOPES = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Classroom service;
    private static String TOPIC_NAME = "projects/temp-260404/topics/temp";
    private static String COURSE_ID = "47737005203";

    static {
        SCOPES.addAll(all());
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        final var HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        service = buildClassroomService(HTTP_TRANSPORT);

//      registerForPushNotifications();

        List<Course> courses = getAllCourses();

        if (courses == null || courses.size() == 0)
            System.out.println("No courses found.");
        else {
            System.out.println("\nCourses:");

            for (var currentCourse : courses)
                System.out.println(currentCourse.getName() + "(" + currentCourse.getId() + ")");
        }
    }

    private static void registerForPushNotifications() throws IOException {
        final var pubSupTopic = new CloudPubsubTopic()
                .setTopicName(TOPIC_NAME);

        final var courseWorkChangesInfo = new CourseRosterChangesInfo()
                .setCourseId(COURSE_ID);

        final var feed = new Feed()
                .setFeedType("COURSE_WORK_CHANGES")
                .set("courseWorkChangesInfo", courseWorkChangesInfo);

        Registration notificationsRegistration = new Registration()
                .setFeed(feed)
                .setCloudPubsubTopic(pubSupTopic);

        pubSupTopic.setFactory(JSON_FACTORY);
        courseWorkChangesInfo.setFactory(JSON_FACTORY);
        feed.setFactory(JSON_FACTORY);
        notificationsRegistration.setFactory(JSON_FACTORY);

        service.registrations().create(notificationsRegistration).execute();
        System.out.println("Successfully registered");
    }

    private static Classroom buildClassroomService(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        final var serviceCredentials = getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT);

        return new Classroom.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, serviceCredentials)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        final var clientSecrets = loadJSONClientSecrets();
        final var dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH));

        final var authenticationFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();

        return redirectToAuthentication(authenticationFlow);
    }

    private static GoogleClientSecrets loadJSONClientSecrets() throws IOException {
        final var credentialFileStream = getCredentialsJSONFile();
        if (credentialFileStream == null)
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);

        return GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(credentialFileStream));
    }

    private static InputStream getCredentialsJSONFile() {
        return TempTest.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }

    private static Credential redirectToAuthentication(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow) throws IOException {
        final var receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    private static List<Course> getAllCourses() throws IOException {
        ListCoursesResponse response = service.courses().list()
                .execute();

        return response.getCourses();
    }
}
```

18. Go to Google Classroom and create your own Classroom for testing purposes.
19. Go to Pub/Sub and create a new topic. Make sure it's set to "Google managed key". Get its name under "Topic name" when it's made. There is a little button for copying the full path.
20. Set the TOPIC_NAME field of the class to a String containing the topic name you just copied
21. Run the code and authorize with all scopes. You will be redirected. Make sure you choose the same account you use Cloud Platform on.
22. Running it will give you a list of your courses and their ID numbers in parentheses. Copy the ID number of the test course you made. It should be outputted to the console after running your code.
23. Set the COURSE_ID field of the class to a String containing the ID you just copied
24. Uncomment line 40 and run the code again
25. You're done with my example

What you just did was authenticate yourself so Google Knows what permissions you're giving it, and it can verify your identity. Then, you sent a JSON request to Google with information about what topic you want updates to be published to, the type of updates to get, and the specific classroom to get these updates from.

I highly, HIGHLY recommend you learn how the structure of the JSON response works here.
Perhaps start [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/registrations).

[This page](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications) on the Google documentation has decent information. It also shows the JSON formatting of the message you'll pull from another program using the Google Pub/Sub API. I have not included that here.

Thank you, and good luck. Sorry, I may edit this question a few times. I'm really tired right now.

Comment: This might be the best explanation of all of this that I've seen yet.  Good job, @HydroPage, thanks for your help.

Comment: It's years old, and certainly outdated in many respects. But if it helps you in any way, I'm happy I was of some assistance. Google APIs are hellish

Comment: so, in order to get messages from the queue we have to call it manually? we don't get the message but we have to pull the message, with a webhook we would get the message real time without pulling right? (I know classroom doesn't have webhooks)