# Unable to register for push notifications with Google Classroom API

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-classroom

I'm trying to register to receive push notifications to receive course work for the Classroom API, but I'm running into a brick wall it seems like, as I just can't seem to figure out what to do.

I am using this to register:

```
const CourseRegistration = classroomAPI.registrations.create();
```

and by looking at the documentation I thought I would just need to supply this:

```
{
    "feed": {
        "feedType": "COURSE_WORK_CHANGES",
        "courseWorkChangesInfo": {
            "courseId": "courseidhere"
        }
    },
    "cloudPubsubTopic": {
        "topicName": "topicnamehere"
    }
}
```

but I always run into this error:

```
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "feed[courseWorkChangesInfo][courseId]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'feed[courseWorkChangesInfo][courseId]' could not be found in request message.
```

It seems to me that I have tried everything to get it to work with no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated; I clearly have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59121505/11551468) or [this](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications) help?

Comment: I actually figured it out by taking a more detailed look the documentation. It needs to be placed in the `requestBody`. Thanks though!